# Combining 2 Tables with the"Same" Primary Key in a function

Tags: sql

i gotta write a function for my database to get the price in the order table from my Article table. I Got 2 tables for articles, 1 for rent items and 1 for sale Items.
Both tables use the Primary Key ItemNo, Sales starting at a ItemNo of 1 and Rent starts with itemNo >=1000.

I wrote the function down below for the table sales and it does also work. I am just not sure how to combine the 2 functions right now to get it from both tables.

Should I use an if-case and wrote the function with if inItemNo>=1000 then function for Rent and else Function Sales or should I use an Join? if I should use a join, I am not quite sure how to use it correctly. May someone can help me.

thanks in advance

```
DELIMITER $$
create or replace function fn_PurchasingPrice(inItemNo int) returns int
begin
    declare OutPurchasingPrice int;
    set OutPurchasingPrice=(select ItemNo
                            from Sales 
                            where ItemNo= inItemNo);

    return ifnull(OutPurchasingPrice,-1);
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: From what you say the ItemNo in these 2 tables are in no way related, they just happen to have the same name

Comment: PS: MySQL and mariaDB are not the same animal any longer. Which one are you actually using

Comment: yeah this is totally right, they just got the same name but in the function I need they are "kinda" related name wise and I don't really know how to write the function to get it work for both tables. per table it does work, but I want a combined one.

Comment: Provide a sample - CREATE TABLE for both tables, INSERT INTO with some data (3-5 rows), desired output(s) for needed function with definite argument value(s), add detailed explanations. PS. Your function shown contains too must excess code.

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind would be to use UNION to make one result from the 2 unrelated tables

Comment: I think we have a DB design issue here. See my answer.

A union? Do we want to return 2 values?

Comment: *Both tables use the Primary Key ItemNo, Sales starting at a ItemNo of 1 and Rent starts with itemNo >=1000.* Does this means that there not exists ItemNo value which is present in both tables?

Comment: @Akina yes, I think that is the point. These tables are not related. The 1,000 idea is very dangerous as, of course as soon as the they sell 1,001 articles, everything collapses into a big mess. **Mzn** is correct, the database design is the main issues here

Comment: What about a function that takes 2 params? A third alternative to creating a relation and having separate functions.

Answer (score 0):

I think we have a database design issue. Here are some options:

What I understand is that you want a function that simply returns that price of something, a rent or sale item.

These items have different itemNo's (PK) stored in their own tables. This implies that they are different entities. The fact that they share a price field, doesn't mean they are related. This means you might want to either:

1. Treat them separately and have two functions that return the price for each `fn_SalePurchasingPrice` and `fn_RentPurchasingPrice`.
2. Create a relationship.
3. If you really don't want a relationship nor two separate function, which I wouldn't really recommend, you can pass 2 PK values into the function, one for each table. You can use it like this: `fnPurchasingPrice(6011, 3048)` and it would return two values using a union.

```
   select price from table1 where table1_id = value1
   union select price from table2 where table2_id = value2
```

The number of items in each table can exceed 1000 and so the fact that one table's PK starts at 1000 is not useful.